# Qt5 Is it possible to retrieve an item's checkstate from a combobox without having a pointer to the model?

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

I know you can do it when you have access to the `QStandardItemModel` but using `combobox->model()` returns a `QAbstractItemModel` which doesn't have the `item(int row, int col)` accessor. I've tried working with `QAbstractItemModel::itemData(QModelIndex)` but can't get it to work as I require.

I just need to get the CheckState of the items, `if(item.checkState() == Qt::Checked) etc...`

Edit: I have this code, can I cast it to a QStandardItem?

```
QModelIndex index(1, 0);
QVariant item = ui->SearchAssessmentCombo->model()->data(index, Qt::CheckStateRole);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare an index yourself, all indices are tied to a model. Internally, the `data()` function will determine that the index you gave in the parameter does not belong to the model and will return null values for everything.

You need to ask your model to give you a valid index before you can use it.

```
QModelIndex index = ui->SearchAssessmentCombo->model()->index(1,0);
```